# Node.js how to return an array from within a asynchronous callback for use in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, return

File called testing.js

I can do whatever I like with the data in saveWeatherData but cannot call this function and return the data without getting 'undefined'
For example if i tried the below code in saveWeatherData it will print out the summary as expected...
console.log(`The summary of the weather today is: ${dataArray[0]}`);

However I want to use these values within another file such as a server file that when connected to will display weather summary temperature etc.
So I need to return an array with these values in it so that I can call this function and get my data stored in an array for further use.

I know that the reason the array --dataArray is returning undefined is because asynchronous code.
The array is returned before we have gotten the data using the callback.

My question, is there anyway to do what I am trying to do?
I tried my best to explain the problem and what I want to do, hopefully its understandable.

Would I have to use a callback inside of a callback? To callback here to return the data when its been fetched?
I just cant get my head about it and have tried multiple things to try and get the result I am looking for.

My last idea and something i would prefer not to do is the use the 'fs' module to save the data to a text or json file for use in my other files through reading the data from the saved file...

I feel im close but cant get over the last hurdle, so ive decided to ask for a little help, even just point me on the right track and Ill continue to try and figure it out.
Phew...

Thank you for your time!

```
const request = require("request");

let dataArray = [];

let saveWeatherData = function(weatherData) {
    dataArray = weatherData;
    return dataArray;
};

let getWeatherData = function(callback) {

    request({
        url: `https://api.forecast.io/forecast/someexamplekey/1,-1`,
        json: true
    }, (error, response, body) => {

        //Creating array to hold weather data until we can save it using callback...
        let array = [];
        if (error) {
            console.log("Unable to connect with Dark Sky API servers.")
        }
        else {
            console.log(`Successfully connected to Dark Sky API servers!\n`);

            array.push(body.currently.summary, body.currently.temperature, body.currently.apparentTemperature, body.currently.windSpeed, body.currently.windBearing);

            callback(array);
        }
    });
};

getWeatherData(saveWeatherData);

module.exports = {
    saveWeatherData
};
```

My Other File...
File called server.js

```
const http = require("http");

const testing = require("./testing");

function onRequest(request, response){
    let data = testing.saveWeatherData();

    console.log(`A user made a request: ${request.url}`);

    response.writeHead(200, {"context-type": "text/plain"});

    response.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    response.write("<html>");
    response.write("<head>");
    response.write("<title>Weather</title>");
    response.write("</head>");
    response.write("<body>");
    response.write("Weather summary for today: " + data[0]);
    response.write("</body>");
    response.write("</html>");

    response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server is now running on port 8888...");
```

Comment: No, `saveWeatherData` cannot work. You will need to export `getWeatherData`, and then you need to pass the code that uses `data` as a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure about what are you trying to do. However, I think you're not exporting what you suppose to be exporting. To avoid the use of so many callbacks you may use async/await.

Change this part of your `server.js`

```
async function onRequest(request, response) {
  let data = await testing.getWeatherData();

  console.log(`A user made a request: ${request.url}`);

  response.writeHead(200, { 'context-type': 'text/plain' });

  response.write('<!DOCTYPE html>');
  response.write('<html>');
  response.write('<head>');
  response.write('<title>Weather</title>');
  response.write('</head>');
  response.write('<body>');
  response.write('Weather summary for today: ' + data[0]);
  response.write('</body>');
  response.write('</html>');

  response.end();
}
```

And this of your testing.

```
let getWeatherData = function() {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    request(
      {
        url: `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/someexamplekey/1,-1`,
        json: true
      },
      (error, response, body) => {
        //Creating array to hold weather data until we can save it using callback...
        let array = [];
        if (error) {
          console.log('Unable to connect with Dark Sky API servers.');
        } else {
          console.log(`Successfully connected to Dark Sky API servers!\n`);
          array.push(
            body.currently.summary,
            body.currently.temperature,
            body.currently.apparentTemperature,
            body.currently.windSpeed,
            body.currently.windBearing
          );
          resolve(array);
        }
      }
    )
  );
};

module.exports = {
  getWeatherData
};
```

It will check for new Weather in each request. If you want to save the result to avoid checking every single time you might need to do something else. But I think for a weather app the important is to keep it updated.

Comment: Why are you declaring `getWeatherData()` as `async`.  You are not using `await` and I don't see any other reason that it is `async`.  Just make it a regular function that returns a promise.  And, you can just use the `request-promise` module that promisifies `request()` for you so you don't have to do that manually.

Comment: I had no intention about that async. But I assume he gets the point, right?

Comment: I was attempting to give you feedback on how you could improve your answer.  You can edit your answer to remove the `async` on `getWeatherData()` since it is not needed and you can improve your answer by showing them how to use request-promise which will be simpler than what you currently show.

Comment: Thank you while I don't fully grasp how this works i'm  going to give it a shot, all I needed was someone to point me in a new direction, im sure i can I can figure this out... thank you for your time...

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you so much, I understand nearly all of it too. Just have to play around with it  bit more and watch some other videos on es6 promises and the use of the aysnc keyword. I kind of understand that part the async but have to look up a bit more and practice, and once again much thanks.

Comment: Sure, that's how you get better. You'll love `async/await`. Good bay callback hell.